# Late '80s or early '90s graphic novel about the Trojan War fought in a distant galaxy, using advanced tech

Tags: story-identification, novel, comics

I've been trying to find this for the last 20 years. It was basically the Trojan War fought in a distant galaxy, using advanced tech.

I think it was called something like 'the Battle of Trajian'.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [The Rise and Fall of the Trigan Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trigan_Empire) by Mike Butterworth?

> The series initially ran from 1965 to 1982, dealing with the long-past
> events of an empire on the distant planet of Elekton. Heavily
> influenced by mythological tales, a number of the societies seemed to
> be based on ancient cultures that had existed in history. Chief among
> these was the Trigan Empire, apparently modelled on Ancient Greece and
> the Roman Empire. This similarity even extended to Trigan City, the
> capital being built on five hills, in a similar fashion to the seven
> hills of Rome. The Trigans flew atmosphere craft. The Trigans'
> clothing was similar to that of the Romans, with many of the populace
> dressed in toga-like garments, or in the case of the soldiery, in
> Greek or Roman-style armour. A similar likeness could be drawn with
> Hericon, the chief rival in power to the Trigans, whose appearance
> seemed to mirror that of elements of the Byzantine Empire, and the
> Persian Empire.
>
> [image]

Comment: I saw the question and was gonna suggest The Trigan Empire...man I loved that series...I was like 9 when it first started and I followed it avidly for a few years (but then came puberty and I got more interested in girls!)

Comment: I loved "The Trigan Empire", but I don't remember it having any connection to the Trojan war (apart from the similarity of the name)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - I was thinking more about themes and look&feel, rather than it literally being the *"Trojan War.... in spaaaaaaace"*

Comment: Trigan Empire and Storm. My 2 absolute favorite comic series. Both with drawings by Don Lawrence. The Storm series (and the Red-Hair spin-off) are still being continued, with 2 Dutch artists having taking over after the demise of Don.